# Create form/s depending child entities in symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I am newbie in Symfony. Now I am creating forms for one entity but I need to create any forms to edit child entities.

For example, If I have `contact` entity and `phone_numbers` as a child entity in this relationship.

How can I edit this phone_number from this contact in the same page? I need to create any forms as phone_numbers has this contact? How Can i do this?

Any clue or reference to manual will be enough!! I will research about it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the embedded forms in the [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html#embedded-forms)